# Sorting Object Arrays if objects have properties of different data types

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain this briefly? I am confused by this part: `cars.sort(function(a, b){return a.year - b.year});`

This is my code. What is `a,b` and why do we use `a.year,b.year` ?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Sort</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var cars = [
{type:"Volvo", year:2016},
{type:"Saab", year:2001},
{type:"BMW", year:2010}]

displayCars();

function myFunction() {
    cars.sort(function(a, b)

    {return a.year - b.year}
    );
    displayCars();
}

function displayCars() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  cars[0].type + " " + cars[0].year + "<br>" +
  cars[1].type + " " + cars[1].year + "<br>" +
  cars[2].type + " " + cars[2].year;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

Comment: a and b are two elements of your array. If the function returns >0, a comes first, if <0 b comes first

Answer (score 0):

`function(a,b){return a.year-b.year}` is part of the compare function which returns a negative positive and a zero value which is used for the sorting.

Check this explanation from MDN

[MDN Link for sort Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

here is the link of [w3School Sort explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function pertaining to arrays.

Specific to your question,
cars is an array of objects. a and b are two elements in the array cars.

```
function myFunction() {
    cars.sort(function(a, b) // take in 2 elements from the array
    // a = {type:"Volvo", year:2016}
    // b = {type:"Saab", year:2001},

    {return a.year - b.year} // a-b is for ascending order
    // return 2016 - 2001
    );
    displayCars();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort>) function accepts as parameter a comparison function.

The comparison gets called for pairs of elements from the collection, and needs to return which is *greater* in terms of the order you're trying to achieve. In this case, it is the year.

The result of the comparison function needs to be `>= 0` if the first element is to be considered greater, `< 0` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The *array.prototype.sor*t need a callback function as parameter. when the sort method sort your array, it call the callback many times and pass to it two objects in your array that needs to be compared. These two objects are here a and b. *array.prototype.sort* method expects the callback to return a positive number, a negative one or zero depending the order you want for a and b. Here, the sort callback compare two cars by year, so to return a negative/positif number or zero, the simplest way is to return *a.year - b.year*.